# Equivalent relations on norms (With inner product)

Tags: inner-products

> For $x,y\in X.$ Where $X$ is an inner product space, Prove that the
>   following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $||x+y||=|||x||+||y||$
> 2. $<x,y>=||x||.||y||$
> 3. $x=\lambda y$ or $y=\lambda x$ for some $\lambda\geq0$

**My attempt**
To prove $1\rightarrow2$, I tried to apply the lemma $||x+y||=||x||^2+2Re<x,y>+||y||^2$, But then I end up with $Re<x,y>=||x||.||y||$

For $2\rightarrow3$ I couldn't see a correct path.

For $3\rightarrow1$ It was able to obtain it by direct substitution of $x=\lambda y$ (Or $y=\lambda x $)in $1$

I would appreciate a help

Comment: $1\to2:  \Vert x+y\Vert ^2 = <x+y,x+y>=<x,x>+2<x,y>+<y,y>\\ $$\;$ so $\\ \Vert x +  y\Vert^2 =(\Vert x \Vert +  \Vert y\Vert )^2=\Vert x \Vert ^2 + 2\Vert x \Vert \Vert y \Vert + \Vert y \Vert ^2 \implies ...$

Comment: @FengShao Real inner product require that. In general $<y,x> =\overline{<x,y>}$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You are assuming the inner product is real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) $\Rightarrow$ (2): to continue,  by Cauchy-Schwarz you have 
$$\| x \| \cdot \|y \|= \operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle \leq | \langle x,y \rangle | \leq \| x \| \cdot \|y \|$$

This implies $\operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle = | \langle x,y \rangle |$. Now, if $\langle x,y \rangle =a+ib$ you get that 
$$a=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
from where you get immediately that $b=0$.

Deduce from here that $\langle x, y\rangle = \operatorname{Re}\langle x,y\rangle = \|x \| \cdot \|y \|$.

(2) $\Rightarrow$ (3) You have equality in Cauchy-Schwarz, thus....

**Added** The C-S says that 
$$| \langle x, y \rangle | \leq \| x \| \cdot \|y \|$$
with equality if and only if $x,y$ are linearly dependent.

Since you have equality, it follows that $x,y$ are linearly dependent, meaning either $x= \lambda y$ or $y = \lambda x$.

Now use $\langle x, y \rangle =\| x \| \cdot \|y \|$ to deduce that $\lambda \geq 0$.

Comment: The explanation for $1 \rightarrow 2$ makes perfect sense! Thank you. 
and could you please elaborate a little bit on $2\rightarrow 3$ as well

Comment: @CharithJeewantha See the addon.

Comment: Also see C-S on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Answer (score 2):

For $2$ implies $3$: assume $x\neq 0$ without loss of generality. The assumption implies that $$\left\|y-\frac{\langle x,y \rangle}{\langle x,x \rangle}x\right\|^2=0.$$
(just expand, using $\|\cdot\|^2=\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.)